# pywinauto no way to maximize a minimized window app

Tags: python, pywinauto

this works perfectly if window is not minimized, but when window is minimized i am not be able to set the focus on it.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

    app = Application(backend="uia")
    try:
          app = app.connect(title_re=".*Bloc*.", visible_only=False)

    except:
          print("Not visible...")
          exit()

    app_top_window = app.top_window()
    app_top_window.maximize()
```

How to workaround this and bring the minimized window to the foreground again?

Comment: What is the output of `print(app.windows())`?

Comment: [<uiawrapper.UIAWrapper - 'Sin título: Bloc de notas', Dialog,
3185156526084505133>]

Answer (score 2):

If `connect` calls works fine, it should work like this:

```
top_window = app.window(title_re=".*Bloc*.", visible_only=False)
top_window.restore().set_focus() # sometimes .restore() is redundant
```

`app.top_window()` is not recommended to use as it sticks to the top window at the moment of `.top_window()` call. Top window may change at any moment. Also it's for visible top window only.

Comment: Thanks @Vasily Ryabov but is not working, nothing happens, window is still minimized

Comment: As I can see in "uia" backend method `.set_focus()` is enough to restore and focus the window. Also try `.maximize()`. If there is some traceback, please post it to the question. Can't believe that nothing happens without any error output.